# How do I fill an array according to distributions for each element in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, probability, distribution

Suppose I have 3 boxes and 3 animals and I want to create an array of boxes containing 1 animal each according to their respective distributions:

```
animals = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bunny"]
boxes = []
```

Where the probabilities are given by

```
       "Cat"   "Dog"   "Bunny"
Box 1   0.3     0.4     0.3    
Box 2   0.2     0.3     0.5
Box 3   0.5     0.3     0.2
```

How would I fill the array of boxes such that the first element is equal to "Cat" at probability 0.3, "Dog" at probability 0.4 and "Bunny" at probability 0.3, the second element is equal to "Cat" at probability 0.2, "Dog" at probability 0.3 etc.

Also, suppose the first element/box is "Cat". To look at the second and third box, we cannot have a probability >0 of changing the first box again since it's already filled with a cat. We can also not have a probability >0 of the second box containing a cat again, since it's already in box 1.

Would this be solved responsibly by scaling the remaining rows/columns to add up to 1 but still have their proportions be the same? For instance if box 1 is a cat, then we would get

```
       "Cat"   "Dog"   "Bunny"
Box 1   1       0       0    
Box 2   0       0.4     0.6
Box 3   0       0.6     0.4
```

Comment: If a cat is in box one, does that mean it cannot be in the other 2 boxes? Also, is there a possibility of any box containing a cat/dog/bunny?

Comment: @AliHassan Yes, there is only 1 of each animal and it can only be put in 1 of each boxes at the same time. At the end all boxes must be filled with 1 animal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). It automatically weights the selection:

```py
boxes = []

animals = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bunny"]
box1 = [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]
box2 = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
# box3 = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2] is commented out because it can be ignored

# Choose the first item to go in box1
boxes.append(random.choices(animals, k = 1, weights = box1))
chosen_ind = animals.index(boxes[0])

# Remove the chosen item from animals and box2
animals.pop(chosen_ind)
box2.pop(chosen_ind)

# Choose the second item
boxes.append(random.choices(animals, k = 1, weights = box2))
chosen_ind = animals.index(boxes[1])

# Remove the chosen item from animals, append the only remaining item
animals.pop(chosen_ind)
boxes.append(animals[0])
```

I am pretty aware that this is not a particularly clean nor scalable way to solve the problem, but it kind of gets the job done for this case.

**Edit**: A new version with a numpy array is this

```
import numpy as np

boxes = []

# n animals to choose from
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny' ... ]   # as many items as needed

# n x n matrix of probabilities
prob = np.array([
    [prob(box1, cat), prob(box1, dog), ...]
    [prob(box2, cat), prob(box2, dog), ...]
    ...
])

for box_ind, box in enumerate(prob):
    boxes.append(random.choices(animals, k = 1, weights = box)
    col_ind = animals.index(boxes[box_ind])
    
    # This line sets the probability of a chosen item to 0 for future iterations
    prob[:, col_ind] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To scale this, would it be possible to create an array of box-distributions, and then iterate over box[0], box[1] etc. instead of box1, box2 etc? Also, does this automatically rescale the probabilities after each selection? Since if you remove lets say cat and box 1, you'll end up with weight 0.3 for dog and 0.5 for bunny, which leaves a weight of 0.2 that nothing will be put -- or will it adjust to 0.3 out of 0.8 and 0.5 out of 0.8 for the weights?

Comment: It will automatically adjust. The example posted in the documentation uses weights of 10, 45, etc. so that's no issue. If I were to make this scalable what I might consider is a numpy array since pure python is probably not efficient for this